# Installing NodeJS v8.9 on Fedora 26

Tags: node.js, fedora-26

I use Fedora 26 and NodeJS v 6.11
Now NodeJS v8.9 recommended for most users.
I downloaded this version( node-v8.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz ) and unpack, but what next? I have tree of folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **nvm** to help you with that, simply do the following.

1. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash`
2. `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`
3. `command -v nvm` (if it outputs **nvm** then it is installed correctly.)
4. `nvm install 8.9.0`

You now have installed Node.js 8.9.0 and Node Package Manager (Latest)